# Gradle configuration on AndroidStudio 1.0X

Tags: gradle, android-studio

I have downloaded a fresh copy of AndroidStudio 1.02 which comes with gradle 2.2.1. My JAVA_HOME points to a java 1.7 installation. In fact I do not even have java 1.4.

Yet I receive this error:

```
Error:Gradle 2.2.1 requires Java 6 or later to run. Your build is currently configured to use Java 4.
```

After searching for an hour on the internet and digging into AndroidStudio settings I cannot get it to work. I'll appreciate if someone can help.

Comment: I guess the problem might have risen because of the residuals of previous installation in my home directory. I removed those directories (.gradle, .AndroidStudio*) and reinstalled a fresh copy. It seems the problem has now been solved. Yet I don't have a clue, how could I solve it by changing the settings.

Answer (score 2):

Try File->Other Settings->Default Project Structure and set JDK Location to Java 6 or later

Comment: Thank you Cristian. The setting was pointing to JDK 1.7 though.

Comment: This solved m poblem. previously It was pointing to 1.5. Thanks.